# vectorize a pandas dataframe operation

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I have a master dataframe of players and their stats after each game, 0.5 million big, and a dataframe( 30K) of team and their rosters of 18 players on various dates. I want to pick the best set of role players, based on their stats, from their roster, say attacker, defender, winger for each team for each date and do it fast. At the moment, my pandas apply solution takes 54 cpu seconds for 1000 rows. I have 50,000 rows so that's going to take  45 minutes or so. I want to do it much faster, say in 10 minutes or so.

I've used apply. Here's the toy example:

```
# this is the master data frame of players and their stats
player_data={'player': ['Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Sally'], 'goals':[1,2,1,2], 'tackles':[4,3,5,3]}
df_players=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(player_data)
# this are the teams and their rosters
team_data={'name':['Cougars','Tigers'], 'roster':[{'Tom', 'Dick'}, {'Harry', 'Sally'}]}
df_teams=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(team_data)

# this is the function called by apply
def get_role_players(x, df_players):
    attacker=df_players[df_players.player.isin(x["roster"])].sort_values("goals", ascending=False).iloc[0].player
    defender=df_players[df_players.player.isin(x.roster)].sort_values("tackles", ascending=False).iloc[0].player
    return pd.Series([x["name"],attacker, defender], index=['team','attacker', 'defender'])

# here I apply the apply function
role_players=df_teams.apply(lambda x: get_role_players(x, 
df_players), axis=1)
print(role_players)
```

And the results are :

```
team    attacker    defender
Cougars Dick    Tom
Tigers  Sally   Harry
```

Comment: `final=df_teams.join(pd.DataFrame(df_teams.roster.tolist(),columns=['attacker','defender'])).drop('roster',1)` or `final=df_teams.join(pd.DataFrame(df_teams.pop('roster').tolist(),columns=['attacker','defender']))`

Comment: I'm not sure it does what I want it to do. Your code seems to convert the set of players to columns. Say I had a roster of 3 players e.g' roster':[{'Tom', 'Dick', 'Abel'}, {'Harry', 'Sally','Bernice'} Then the code will try to create 3 columns and fails with :   AssertionError: 2 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns       . Your code doesn't use the players_data dataframe, df_players, at all, when its to be used to decide who is the best attacker in the roster, based on goals scored, who is the best defender based on tackles made.